# Module Not Found Error: No Module Named 'my_project.settings' django gunicorn

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy on heroku but first I am trying to run on my machine but I keep getting the Module Not Found Error. My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

To make it more clear, I have a folder called 'imperialtheatre' that holds the venv and requirements and inside that folder i have a folder called 'imperialtheatre' which holds the django project with `manage.py` etc.

Why am I getting this error?

I am running this command:

`gunicorn imperialtheatre.imperialtheatre.wsgi:application -t 120 -w 8 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --log-level debug`

wsgi.py file:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "imperialtheatre.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your settings file located within the settings folder. Change

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "imperialtheatre.settings")
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "imperialtheatre.settings.settings_file")
```

Replacing `settings_file` with the name of your actual settings file.

Also ensure there is an `__init__.py` file in the settings directory. If not, just save a blank file called `__init__.py` there.